# "unsupported FastCGI protocol version" error with nginx and php-cgi under high load

Tags: nginx, wordpress, php-cgi

I'm running a **Wordpress** site with `NGINX` and `php5-cgi`. My setup works, in principle.

However, when there are requests in close succession, I sometimes see  this strange error:

```
[error] 5057#0: *706 upstream sent unsupported FastCGI protocol version: 72 while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.45.67.89, server: www.some.domain, request: "GET /some-subpage/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:12345", host: "www.some.domain", referrer: "http://www.some.domain/some-subpage/"
```

This will happen even if I have only two subsequent requests, if both involve PHP sources.

My upstream does `fastcgi_pass` the request to a socket which should be capable of dealing with several requests. I create the socket like this:

```
/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -s /path-to/some.sock -P /path-to/some.pid -C 8 -f /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

**What did I configure wrong?**

** i didnt use php'fpm because it is version 5.3.3 and for some reason i cant manage to update it to 7.x+ and when i serve my site with php-fpm my theme and plugins are all messed up dur to the old php version :(

Comment: Is there any reason you do not use `php-fpm`? It is certainly a popular approach, which means well tested.

Comment: Most likely reason here is that `php-cgi` simply cannot handle large loads due to its architecture. Use `php-fpm`.